# How to solve the error LNK2019 IN OPNET?

Tags: visual-c++

How do I fix this error?

```
<<< Recoverable Error >>>
Object repository construction failed
due to errors encountered by the binder program (bind_so_msvc)
T (0), EV (-), MOD (NONE), PROC (sim_load_repos_rebuild)
----
Errors reported by the binder program follow
(these messages have been saved in (C:\Users\hassan\op_admin\tmp\bind_err_2032):
   Creating library C:\OPNET\14.5.A\models\op_models\pksw_net.project\pksw_net-baseline.dev32.i0.nt.lib and object C:\OPNET\14.5.A\models\op_models\pksw_net.project\pksw_net-baseline.dev32.i0.nt.exp

dpt_propdel.dev32.i0.ps.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _link_delay referenced in function _dpt_propdel_mt

C:\OPNET\14.5.A\models\op_models\pksw_net.project\pksw_net-baseline.dev32.i0.nt.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals


----
<<< Program Abort >>>
Error encountered rebuilding repository -- unable to proceed
T (0), EV (-), MOD (NONE), PROC (sim_load_repos_load)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a binder/linker error. Make sure the compiler/linker system environment settings are configured correctly.